# How do I tell search engines about my flash content?

Tags: seo

I use the embed & object tag combo to display SWF's.  Just like we use alt for img, how do I tell search engines what content my SWF contains?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lately google introduced indexing swf text content, and maybe other engines will follow.
For details see http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2008/06/improved-flash-indexing.html

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there's no "ALT" specific for SWF. Google can read the contents just fine though, as long as you don't hide it behind Javascript (generating the tags on the fly or upon page load).